# Exception while executing the powershell script for Sitecore 9.0 installation XP0

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 XP0 as standalone instance on my Windows 8.1 machine. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the installation guide but in the final step I am getting a private key error as below:

```
[TIME] 00:00:03
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\windows\system32\xconnect-xp0.180123 (3).log
GetConfigFunctionResult : Unable to parse [ResolveCertificatePath(variable('Security.XConnect.CertificatePath'))] -
Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference
variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Certificate
Cert:\Localmachine\My\FA59DE90DE6223841D34D03700F5C2251303815D does not contain Private Key. Ensure that it has been
exported with the Private Key."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.1.0\Private\JsonConfiguration.ps1:182 char:20
+ ...      return GetConfigFunctionResult -FunctionText $InputObject -Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,GetConfigFunctionResult
```

I have checked the certificate in `Certificate store` and it has a valid private key associated with it. Still I am not able to proceed any further. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Have you executed the xconnect-createcert.json prior to xconnect-xp0.json?

Comment: Sitecore 9.0 update 1 has resolved some of the certificate issues that we encountered in Windows 8.1. Can you go with Sitecore XP 9.0.1?

Comment: @phani - This is not a problem of Sitecore installation package but SIF itself. You need to use latest version of SIF to resolve this exception during installation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the powershell script mentioned at https://sitecore.namics.com/2017/12/15/make-sif-work-with-windows-8-1-and-iis-8-5/ which includes cmdlet for windows 8.1. The original install script which is mentioned in the installation guide doesnot work with windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use latest version of Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) which is as of writting this answer version 1.2. This version is specifically targeted to resolve this issue.

From release notes:
- Invoke-ResolveCertificatePathConfigFunction - Correctly resolves certificate private key path on Windows 8.1/2012

Take a look here for further information:

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Installation%20Framework/1x/Sitecore%20Installation%20Framework%2012/Release%20Notes

and

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Installation_Framework/1x/Sitecore_Installation_Framework_12.aspx

I also recommend to install SIF through official Sitecore PowerShell gallery feed. Take a look here https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_powershell_public_nuget_feed_faq .

You can also follow my blog post http://tothecore.sk/2018/06/22/sitecore-9-update-2-sitecore-9-0-2-installation (Chapter 1) with instructions how to do that.